# Unhandled Exception: Content size below specified contentLength. 511 bytes written but expected 704

Tags: file, flutter, flutter-http

I'm trying to upload text and pdf files 
    code below but I'm receiving the error in the content size. I'm following
    the code in the document but I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right 
    way. Thanks in advance

```
Future<void> _postCallCreate(String fileNames, String urlSegment) async {
Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': _token,
};

final url = Constants.BASE_URL + urlSegment;
try {
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
  request.files.add(http.MultipartFile(
      'dto',
      File(fileNames).readAsBytes().asStream(),
      File(fileNames).lengthSync(),
      filename: fileNames.split("/").last));

  print(request.files.first);

  request.headers.addAll(requestHeaders);
  var res = await request.send();

  print(res.reasonPhrase);
  notifyListeners();
} catch (error) {
  print(error);
  throw error;
}
}
```

Comment: There's a convenience function that handles creating the `MultipartFile` from a path: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartFile/fromPath.html Give that a try, as it reduces errors.

Comment: @RichardHeap I  have also try this mentioned link method but its showing same error